# Zsh: prepend $(<list.txt) args with a directory

Tags: macos, script, zsh, cp, mv

I'm using `cp $(<list.txt) new_folder` to copy a list of files (filenames in `list.txt`) to a new folder. As is the files must be in the same folder as `list.txt`.

Is there an easy way to make this work if the actual files are in a separate directory from `list.txt`? Perhaps prepend each filename with a path?

Answer (score 1):

`$(<list.txt)` is using process substitution so you can throw whatever command you want in between the brackets to munch the contents of `list.txt` to your hearts content.

Something like `cp $(sed -e 's/^/path\/goes\/here\//' list.txt) new_folder` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!  Trying `cp $(sed -e 's/^source_dir\//' list.txt) target_dir` but getting a "unescaped newline inside substitution pattern" error.  FYI - `list.txt` is in the parent directory of both `source_dir` and `target_dir`.

Comment: If this is a one off thing you're going to be doing I'd just move list.txt inside source_dir and add ../ to the front of the replacement pattern. It sounds easier than fighting sed. I'm assuming you haven't got a literal newline in the replacement pattern for sed?